# Chess in Python without any game library?

Tags: python

I'm already starting with my project in Python, but before I start, I would like to ask - am I able to create a Chess Game in Python, without the need of downloading any game library (like Pygame)? I should create a game using tkinter.

Comment: You can create a chess game using anything you want.  You could first rewrite both Pygame and tkinter (just so you have a backup) all by yourself, and then use one of those.

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean by rewriting Pygame?

Comment: tkinter gives you window toolkit, using which you can create various UI elements. Try building a windows style calculator first and then start with chess.

Comment: Yes, of course it is *possible*. You could write it in assembly if you wish.

Comment: I was being sarcastic.  You should start with a game library if it saves you work and does what you want to do.  As other answers say, you could write a text game all by yourself or you could write a graphics game, in which case you'd benefit greatly from a library that handled all the screen logic for you.  As other said, the game logic itself is one thing, and how to display the board and allow the user to move the pieces is another.  Anything is possible.  it's up to you.

Comment: @Steve please note that I'm not advanced in Python, so everything you say saracastic, I take seriously. ;) Anyway I appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 2):

The interface is actually not related to the chess game at all -
So, you could make a game to play chess with print statements on the terminal, and just use capital and small letters to represent the pieces, like "rkbqkbkr" - and the gameplay part would be independent.

And yes, tkinter is a fully capable windowing toolkit - it only lacks image and text rotation calls - but you can use tkinter to play chess, and won't even need PIL, which is also an external library needed by tkinter to load images, because the chess pieces thenselves are available as unicode characters 
♔♕♖♗♘♙♚♛♜♝♞♟  (these also would work for the terminal version)

Moreover, actual serious chess software don't even have to implement an interface at all - there are text-communication protocols that are used by a number of programs which can work in symbiosis - one program, like xchess or gnome-chess working displaying only the graphic interface, and the actual game engine working in text only.

Comment: Thank you. I have already made several games using only console, that's why I want to move forward to GUI.

Comment: A tkinter board should be pretty easy to code if you setup a grid of labels and display the unicode chars in them.

Comment: But remember, as already said that the game itself doesn't depend on board display.

Answer (score 2):

Game libraries do not grow on trees. Someone had to create it first which means theoretically you can write all the code too. But people are using exiting solutions to focus on their creation and not on reinventing the wheels like all the base features each game needs as it takes both skills and time -> it simply "costs". So yes, you can go fully own path. Should you? It's up to you.